# Callstack sampling in Erlang

Tags: erlang, profiling

I am currently investigating a performance issue within a large Erlang application. The application exhibits larger-than-expected CPU load. To get a first grasp which parts of the system are responsible for the load, I'd like to perform callstack sampling as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/436853).

Is there a better way to do this than calling `erlang:process_info(Pid, backtrace)` repeatedly and grepping the functions from that output?

Note that the system is too large to use `fprof`, and that `etop` did not point me into the right direction as well. Using `fprof` for only parts of the system is not possible right now as well, as I first need to pin-point the general location of the performance issue.

Comment: I don't know Erlang, but I know that technique. Can you run your program under a debugger, manually pause it, and examine the call stack? I wouldn't worry about first finding the general location of the performance issue, because if it takes a big percent of time that's the probability you will see it, and if it takes a small percent, chances are something else you didn't suspect takes a big percent.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey thanks for the suggestion (I just learned how to suspend and resume processes in Erlang because of it). Although Erlang allows suspending processes, I do not see a way yet to simplify callstack sampling. With `erlang:process_info(Pid, backtrace)`, I can retrieve stack traces at runtime and do not need to suspend processes myself. But then I am left with parsing that output.

Comment: It's important *not* to put the sampling into the code. It has to happen at a time that's unpredictable from the viewpoint of the program. The other point is that you don't need a lot of samples (contrary to widespread assumption). You only need to see a problem twice to know it's worth fixing, and the average number of samples needed for that is 2 / size_of_problem. So if the problem costs 30% of time, the average number of samples needed to see it twice is 2 / 0.30 = 6.67 samples.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get the actual size of the stack is `process_info(Pid, stack_size)`. While this only return the size of the stack in words it is a very simple and efficient way of seeing which processes have large stacks.

Comment: Wouldn't `reductions` be the better measure to determine the origin of large load? I would expect that the processes putting much load on the system will display a consistently large number of `reductions`. Preliminary tests with `stack_size` were inconclusive (or I misinterpreted the numbers)

Comment: Yes, `reductions` would be a better measure but this was a comment the original question asking about an alternative to `backtrace`.